# T-SQL insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert

The database I am working on has the following insert trigger. The problem is the trigger will not work with a multi-row insert. When I try and insert more than one row at a time I get the following message.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _ti_UD06, Line 8
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression. I think the problem is with the following statement it
>   will return more than one value when multiple rows are inserted.

How can I make this insert trigger work with multiple rows?

```
IF(SELECT PROGRESS_RECID FROM inserted) IS NULL
```

There are 2 columns in the table, `PROGRESS_RECID` and `PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_`.

I think the `PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_` is an `Identity` column for SQL Server. The `PROGRESS_RECID_INDENT` is used by the PROGRESS Server.

If a new record is inserted the trigger checks to see if the `PROGRESS_RECID` is null and will set it to the `inserted.Identity`

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[_ti_UD06] ON [dbo].[UD06] for insert as
begin
if  ( select PROGRESS_RECID from inserted) is NULL
    begin
        update t set PROGRESS_RECID = i.IDENTITYCOL
        from UD06 t JOIN INSERTED i ON
        t.PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_ = i.PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_
        select convert (bigint, @@identity)
    end
end
```

Here is the Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UD06](
[Company] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
[Key1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Key2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Key3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Key5] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Character01] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character02] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character03] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character04] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character05] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character06] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character07] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character08] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character09] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Character10] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[SysRowID] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
[SysRevID] [int] NULL,
[BitFlag] [int] NULL,
[GlobalUD06] [tinyint] NULL,
[GlobalLock] [tinyint] NULL,
[PROGRESS_RECID] [bigint] NULL,
[PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close already:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[_ti_UD06] ON [dbo].[UD06] for insert as
begin

    UPDATE t 
    SET    PROGRESS_RECID = t.PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_  --not "IDENTITYCOL"
    FROM   UD06 t 
    JOIN   inserted i ON  t.PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_ = i.PROGRESS_RECID_IDENT_
    WHERE  i.PROGRESS_RECID is Null

    -- Not sure what this bit is for?  I doubt it's a good idea though...
    select convert (bigint, @@identity)

end
```

Comment: I made the changes, I no longer get the error, but the PROGRESS_RECID is null after the insert.

Comment: @Kevin We'd need to see the table definition to go any further.

Comment: Here is sthe table definition.